# System() only return the first line of command result

Tags: c, linux

Regard to System() function, when I pass a command: "ps -p pid -o command" to system() function, it only return the first line of result:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {

system("ps -p 5819 -o command");
return 0;
}
```

The result :

```
COMMAND
```

But if i pass command "ls -l" to system() function, it is workable.

Is anyone has the same issue?
Thank you !

Comment: The `-p` option selects a single PID (Process ID) and shows only the information for that specific PID. Which for the `command` format is usually a single line. What did you expect to see?

Comment: The output will be a single line, containing the column heading "COMMAND", if the specified process (in this case 5819) does not exist.  If the specified process does exist then the output will be two lines, the first containing the column heading and the second showing the command name and arguments of the specified process.